# Strapi : debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly

Tags: mongodb, flutter, debugging, server, strapi

Please fix my problem.

It works when I try more than 50 times. Now it does not work I try 100+ times.

I start this ->  strapi new server

```
� Starting to create your Strapi application.

? Choose your installation type Custom (manual settings)
? Choose your main database: MongoDB
? Database name: server
? Host: @cluster0-8tfpd.mongodb.net
? +srv connection: true
? Port (It will be ignored if you enable +srv): 27017
? Username: deep
? Password: *******
? Authentication database (Maybe "admin" or blank):
? Enable SSL connection: true

⏳ Testing database connection...
It might take a minute, please have a coffee ☕️

The app has been connected to the database successfully!

�  Application generation:
√ Copy dashboard
√ Install plugin settings-manager.
√ Install plugin content-type-builder.
√ Install plugin content-manager.
√ Install plugin users-permissions.
√ Install plugin email.
√ Install plugin upload.
√ Link strapi dependency to the project.

� Your new application server is ready at E:\Dev. Project\Flutter\flutter_ecommerce\server.

⚡️ Change directory:
$ cd server

⚡️ Start application:
$ strapi start
```

But problem is -> strapi start

> [2019-06-15T09:34:30.604Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
>   [2019-06-15T09:34:30.609Z] error Make sure your MongoDB database is running...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Have you checked to see if your MongoDB instance is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you face this error while working with docker, 
Adding `--network=host` solves this problem. Keep in mind, use this solution only locally.

As described by docker itself,

> --network="host" gives the container full access to local system services such as D-bus and is therefore considered insecure.

Comment: Adding `--network=host` where?

Answer (score 6):

[See the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Ftq.png)

You should add an entry `uri` into your `./config/environment/.../database.json`

`uri` should be `mongodb://<host>:<port>/<database name>`

Comment: This solution helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your MongoDB is running with the settings you set in your `./config/environment/.../database.json`

I think your host have ans issue, `@` is not needed.

I suggest you to follow the Strapi doc about Mongo Atlas docs.
That work with clusters.
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/databases.html#install-on-atlas-mongodb-atlas

Answer (score 0):

1. Check is MongoDB instance is running
2. Check in the settings that `host` is correct: `./config/environment/.../database.json`. Usually in development is `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

If this error happens again, then go with **strapi console** rather than **strapi start**

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but when I was installing it i used sudo  and when i tried to start the strapi server without sudo it didn't work but when I used sudo  npm run develop and it worked successfully

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue
debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
error: Cannot read property 'extensions' of undefined

It is resolved after removing the "^" character
from "@strapi/plugin-documentation": "^4.2.0" to "4.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to your database being not accessible.

In my case, I had to start Docker on macOS, then run my backend container that handle my PostgreSQL database.