# ReactNative x MongoDB : Unable to start my project

Tags: mongodb, react-native, strapi

I want to start a project with React Native and MongoDB but, after creating my project (with all default settings), I run the command 'strapi start' in the project folder and i get nothing but an error.

I am pretty beginner with reactnative, strapi, command lines and so on, maybe i forget something important ?

```
[2020-02-17T11:07:42.307Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2020-02-17T11:07:42.308Z] error Invalid empty username provided
Invalid empty username provided
```

I don't understand how to start my projet using MongoDB. I hadn't any problem with SQLite.

```
npm : 6.13.4
nodejs : 10.19.0 
mongodb : 3.4.24
strapi : 3.0.0.alpha.26.2
```

If someone know what I can do to resolve this issue, it would be very nice !

Thank you so much and have a good day.

Comment: I think this is related to mongodb server ? Not on your react native side ?

Comment: Follow this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609285/strapi-debug-%EF%B8%8F-server-wasnt-able-to-start-properly

Comment: I would like to also point out that Strapi Alpha is no longer supported and contains at least 2 critical security issues:

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-18818
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-19609

You should consider updating to the beta ASAP.

Comment: @AkilaDevinda everything seems to be OK on the side of Mongodb

> sudo systemctl status mongodb
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-02-17 13:58:26 CET; 30s ago

Comment: @DerrickMehaffy Maybe I miss something but I didn't manage to migrate, following this tuto : https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/migration-guide/migration-guide-alpha.26-to-beta.html

Comment: Your best bet is to start a new fresh project and migrate your models manually (not just copy the whole API folder)