# Strapi - Server wasn't able to start properly

Tags: mongodb, flutter, strapi

I'm building app in Flutter. I have connected Strapi with Mongodb Atlas.
Everything was fine until suddenly I'm getting this kind of error:

```
[2020-08-03T17:03:26.651Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2020-08-03T17:03:26.652Z] error Error connecting to the Mongo database. Server selection timed out 
after 30000 ms
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@0.1.0 develop: `strapi develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@0.1.0 develop script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

My cluster is connected and I know no idea what could go wrong.
Any idea what should I do?

Comment: just check by changing host from localhost to 127.0.0.1 in database.json

Comment: The host in file 'database.js' has path to the mongodb. something like `host: env('DATABASE_HOST', '@ecommerce.equmf.mongodb.net') `

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609285/strapi-debug-%EF%B8%8F-server-wasnt-able-to-start-properly

Comment: Already saw this question, but none of the answers helped me

Comment: Just try restarting it completely.

Comment: How do i restart it completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my ip has changed. So what i had to do is to add in mongodb atlas my new ip.
In my Cluster -> SECURITY -> Netwrok Access - ADD IP ADDRESS.

And thats its